# Can't return only usernames from json data fetched through a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am able to get json data from an external php page and print it on the JavaScript console. But these are in the form objects. The following is the data I recieved on my console:

```
[{"id":"1","username":"iammuneeb","password":"4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93","name":"Mirza Muneeb"},{"id":"2","username":"iamfaiz","password":"4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93","name":"Faiz"}]
```

How can I extract only username and turn it into an ordered list. (ol)

This is what I have done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#delete').click(function (e) {
        var jsonData = getResultsInJson(username);
        jsonData.success(function (data) {
            var output = "<ol>";
            for (var i in data) {
                output += "<li>" + data.username + "</li>";
            }
            output += "</ol>";
            $('#placeholder').html(data);
            console.log(data.username);
        });
    });
});
```

This is getResultsInJson():

```
function getResultsInJson(sql) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'commands.php',
        data: 'results=' + sql,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `i.username`???

Comment: then don't return the password etc in the PHP. this is more of a PHP problem than the javascript

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: The basic problem here is that you are doing:     `$('#placeholder').html(data);` where it should be     `$('#placeholder').html(output);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use the `for(x in y)` format, x is the key, and y is the array or object. Since i is just the key, you need to use it as one:

```
 for (var i in data) {
            output += "<li>" + data[i].username + "</li>";
        }
```

Comment: still getting only one username while there are two usernames?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need them in alphabetically?

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var json = [{"id":"1","username":"iammuneeb","password":"4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93","name":"Mirza Muneeb"},{"id":"2","username":"iamfaiz","password":"4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93","name":"Faiz"}];

    var usernames = new Array();
    $.each(json, function(index, object) {
       usernames[index] = object.username;
    });
    var sorted = usernames.sort();

    var output = '';
    $.each(sorted, function(index, value) {
         output += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
    });
     $('#placeholder').html('<ol>' + output + '</ol>');
});
```